# Reference requested: algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I have to study 'D-Modules, Perverse Sheaves, and Representation Theory' by Hotta,Takeuchi, Tanisaki and I am having problems with the algebraic machinery they use. I know what's a scheme and what is an algebraic variety but I don't know neither what is the tangent sheaf to an algebraic variety or theorems about the cohomology of quasi-coherent sheaves and things like those which they often use. Could someone give me some reference? I was thinking about 'Basic Algebraic Geometry I' by Shafarevich for what concerns tangent/cotangent sheaf, is it a good idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Vakil's notes are frequently suggested here but I am not an algebraic geometer so I don't really know.

Comment: A good reference is Hartshorne, chapter 3 for cohomology which contains many theorems (sometimes they are hidden in the exercices...). There is also a section about the differential. Also, it was hard for me to read this book and a nice complement (in case you are interested by perverse sheaves) was this article : http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-04/S0273-0979-09-01260-9/S0273-0979-09-01260-9.pdf
Good luck !